# How do I fix or correct the "Default File Template" warning in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

IntelliJ Idea: 2016.1
Windows 10 Pro

When I create a new project or a new class in a new project, IntelliJ helpfully includes a default header containing my name and the date. However, it also highlights the code and displays a warning about the file using a "Default File Template". It suggests two ways to correct the code. Either by editing the template or by replacing it with an actual file template. However, neither option satisfies the warning; nor does manually replacing the contents of the header. I can't figure out a way to get rid of it.

[image]

I know that I can suppress the warning, but I would prefer to actually correct or fix it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add a new line after Default Template statement which has name and date.
Intellij considers that new line as part of documentation, and then stops complaining.
**Update**

Like this:

```
/**
 * Created by YourName on 2017/06/11.
 * THIS LINE
 */
```

Comment: In 12 month you will look back at the file fixing a last minute bug. In this moment you desperately look for help in the description, but the only help you get is an empty line. I suggest using a link to this stackoverflow instead of an empty line.

Comment: @HeikoG,  if you need documentation for every class or function in your code, then you are not using proper naming for you objects.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Ctrl + Alt + L` brings it back. Shame there really isn't a way to permanently remove the warning.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu Yes if you will do reformatting, it will bring it back. So the key is to put some comment on new line e.g. just a 'dot' or some useful comment.

Comment: You can simply remove the "dot" after the date and save template. Then the warning will disappear. There is no need to add a new line!

Comment: Just verified that this annoying warning doesn't appear in new Intellij (2018 Ulitmate). So no workaround is needed.

Answer (score 39):

The point of it is to remind you to document your code by adding a description of the class. No matter what you set the template to, if you don't change the text that is in the template, it assumes you want a reminder to override it with some useful information.  If you are not in the habit of adorning your code with informative comments, then you can disable that particular check.

To disable the check, where you see the comment block highlighted as a warning, click in that shaded area, wait for the "light bulb" intention icon to appear near the left margin, then, when it pops up a box that says "Edit template...", instead of clicking on the words, click on the little arrow to the right of the words, and select "Disable inspection".

Comment: In intellij 14, clicking the little arrow to the right of "edit template" brings up the same menu as does clicking the text. I fixed it under the "Inspections" section of settings

Answer (score 7):

Change the default template anyway you want and then the error is gone!

[image]

Comment: This resolves, because you need to remove the second * for stop the annoying warning.

Perfect answer even with the gif and don't need to do something all the time your create a new file

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> File and Code Templates -> includes

Update the comment to add an extra line like below..This stays even after formatting the code.

```
 /**
    * Created by ${USER} 
    * on ${DATE}.
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

Press Alt+Enter inside the comment and after that use rightwards-arrow on your keyboard to get a submenu where you can disable the lint check.

Answer (score -1):

Add `-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false` in Help | Edit Custom VM Options.