# I am trying to share a project in github using IntelliJ IDEA but i gives a following error

Tags: java, spring, github, intellij-idea, share

[image]

when i click **Review** it gives following warning message.

[image]

My project is not update in github. How to solve that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those warnings are nothing more than warnings. You can just click "commit" and continue as normal. They mean you haven't documented your code. See here: [How do I fix or correct the "Default File Template" warning in IntelliJ Idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36947709/how-do-i-fix-or-correct-the-default-file-template-warning-in-intellij-idea)